# Ember liquid-fire animation complete

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to find out in the Route when the liquid-outlet animation is complete?

For example I would like to load certain data after animation is complete.

Comment: Since liquid-fire is promised based, using .then should execute a function after the animation is done. To trigger a method in your route you may need to pub/sub system using Ember.Evented. Something like this should help http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/04/27/event-bus/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Animation Primitives** to determine if an animation has finished.
Take a look at the available primitives in the docs [Animation Primitives](http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/#/transitions/primitives/three).

In your case the **finish** primitive would return a promise which will resolve when the animation is completed. You will have to pass in the animated element and the label e.g.

```
var ended;
ended = finish(animatedElem, 'toLeft');
ended.then( // load your data );
```

Comment: I'd like to load my data in from the Route. Can those primitives be accessed from a Route?